# Removing vowels from an input string using a loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, input

I need my output to only be 5 characters long NOT counting the removed vowels. Currently my code is counting the input length and returning that number minus the vowels. This might be confusing. If I input "idontthinkso" it only returns "dnt" instead of what I want it to print out which is "dntth". Btw, I'm not allowed to use Stringbuilder or anything like that, only a loop, so forgive the code. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TweetCompressor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "";
        System.out.println("Type a tweet: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        int f = 0;
        int tweetLengthAllowed = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < tweetLengthAllowed; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (c == 'a' ||
                    c == 'e' ||
                    c == 'i' ||
                    c == 'o' ||
                    c == 'u' ||
                    c == 'A' ||
                    c == 'E' ||
                    c == 'I' ||
                    c == 'O' ||
                    c == 'U') {
                f = 1;
            } else {
                s = s += c;
                f = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm **very** much in favor of using a while loop for this, but since you stated you can only use a for loop...

The problem is that your loop will iterate until i = 5, even if a vowel is detected. We need a way to tell the loop to pretend that never happened. You can't decrement i, or you'll be stuck at the same character forever.

Here's what I came up with, I decided to simply increment the `tweetLengthAllowed` to negate the i increment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";
    System.out.println("Type a tweet: ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    int f = 0;
    int tweetLengthAllowed = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < tweetLengthAllowed; ++i) { //Must be a for loop
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        if(c == 'a'|| c == 'e'|| c == 'i'|| c == 'o'|| c =='u' || 
            c == 'A' || c == 'E' ||  c == 'I' ||  c == 'O' || c == 'U') {

            f = 1;
            tweetLengthAllowed++; //Allows the loop to continue for one more interation
        } //end if
        else{
            s = s += c;
            f = 0;
        }//end else
    } //end for
    System.out.println(s);

} //end main
} //end class
```

Also, if you're going to use a big chain of ORs, please do yourself a favor and make it more readable as I did above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simpler. Here I iterate every char in the input and break if it reaches the limit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TweetCompressor  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "";
        System.out.println("Type a tweet: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        int tweetLengthAllowed = 5;
        int i = 0;
        boolean isNotVowel;
        boolean limitReached;

        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            isNotVowel = "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) == -1;
            limitReached = tweetLengthAllowed <= i;

            if (limitReached) { // exit the loop
                break;
            } else if (isNotVowel) { // append the char
                s += c;
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Run output:

> Type a tweet:
>   idontthinkso
>   dntth

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of doing it:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class Program {

    private static String RemoveVowel(String text)
    {
        int len = text.length();
        char[]vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text);
        for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)
        {
            for(char v : vowels)
            {
                if(v == text.charAt(i)) 
                {
                    sb.setCharAt(i,'\0');
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter some text to remove vowels from it: ");
        String val = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(RemoveVowel(val));
    }

}
```

I have used string buffer to make the string modifiable and a "for" loop iterates through the length of the string, and one iterates through the "vowels" array; an "if" statement checks if the current character is equal to one of the vowels and if true, it sets the current character to null, which removes the vowel.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RemoveVowels {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputString = "Java - Object Oriented Programming Language";
        System.out.println(inputString.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", " "));    
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
J v  -  bj ct  r  nt d Pr gr mm ng L ng  g
```